# Rails and embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

For my website I have the following title helper:

```
<% provide(:title, 'My Page') %>
```

Which produces something like this:

[image]

Instead of the generic 'My Page' I'm trying to add the user name, for instance 'mtcrts70'. To do this I tried the following code:

```
<% provide(:title, '<%= current_user.email[/[^@]+/] %>') %>
```

Note that <%= current_user.email[/[^@]+/] %> renders perfectly when outside of the <% %> tags.

It seems like the issue is putting <%= %> inside of <% %>. Is there a way to get around this?

Error message:

```
SyntaxError in Static_pages#home

Showing /home/matt/Documents/Ruby/rails_projects/ninja_speak_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb where line #4 raised:

/home/matt/Documents/Ruby/rails_projects/ninja_speak_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
... ;@output_buffer.safe_concat('\') %>
...                               ^
/home/matt/Documents/Ruby/rails_projects/ninja_speak_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
       ');@output_buffer.append= ( cur...
         ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's inside `<% %>` is a piece of normal Ruby code. You just need to pass in the value as argument to the `provide` helper method.

```
<% provide(:title, current_user.email[/[^@]+/]) %>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'll accept answer when SO allows.

Comment: @mtcrts70 Do you understand why that works and your code didn't?

Comment: not exactly, if you want to add a little color that would be great.